# Intent with setType("message/rfc822") for Android API Level before 2.3.3

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a problem with setting type **"message/rfc822"** for intent to send e-mail **with file attachment** on **Android emulator**. I have to use setType("message/rfc822") because the file doesn't have standard MIME-type (SQLite database) and I am trying to avoid a lot of applications in the select list for user's choice. **For all API Levels before 2.3.3** I have an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.cashwatcher/my.cashwatcher.SendEmailActivity}: 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=message/rfc822 
(has extras) }
```

In the case of API Level, 2.3.3 code works fine and error doesn't appear. Is it a problem with the Android emulator or old APIs!?

Code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);                         
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");            
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL , new String[]{appPrefs.getEmail("email")});                   
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DATABASE_PATH)));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body_of_email"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "APPLICATION_NAME");
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, EMAIL_SEND_RESULT);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, "to avoid a lot of applications in select list for user's choice", use `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri`.

Second, what you are experiencing is not "a problem of Android emulator" nor "old APIs". You need 1+ applications that are capable of handling the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` and a MIME type of `message/rfc822`. There is no guarantee that any given device will support that combination, let alone any given emulator. Your code needs to handle that, just as if you use `ACTION_GOBBLEDYGOOK` or a MIME type of `thisis/sonotreal` or whatever.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide some example for "ACTION_SENDTO and a mailto: Uri"

Comment: @isabsent: Would you be so kind as to use the search box, located in the upper right corner of this page?

Comment: I have read a lot from SO and Google before post this question. All of them does not contain a solution on the problem. I realize that I can write all that I want up to my own operating system for android devices, but the aim of asking this question was to know **does appropriate way already exist?**

Comment: @isabsent: [Here is a link to the search results for searching StackOverflow for `ACTION_SENDTO` and `mailto`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ACTION_SENDTO+mailto), which contain examples of using `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri`. This is what I asked you to do in my previous comment, and what you failed to do before posting your original comment.

Comment: I have asked you to provide some code example for "ACTION_SENDTO and a mailto: Uri" **for sending e-mail with (not specified by MIME-type) attachment**. I suppose it is clear from my first question. I have read most from your link before asking this question. **There is nothing essential to help me with the question**. More over, it seems impossible to make attachment with "mailto:" unfortunately.

Comment: @isabsent: "I suppose it is clear from my first question" -- not especially, as I took your request literally. "More over, it seems impossible to make attachment with "mailto:" unfortunately" -- once again, that will depend on clients. There may be some email clients that support `EXTRA_STREAM` with `ACTION_SENDTO`. However, I agree that it appears to be unpopular and therefore won't help. Your current approach is probably as good as it gets. Just either catch `ActivityNotFoundException` or use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find out ahead of time if the request will fail.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I have found your explicit explanation how to handle "message/rfc822" at this place http://www.androiddiscuss.com/1-android-discuss/95167.html

Answer (score 3):

I have made an application that uses URI example as you desired:

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.button3)
{
    intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto"));
    String[]to={"akshkatheria@gmail.com","megakatheria@gmail.com"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hello");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hi");
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    chooser=intent.createChooser(intent, "send mail");
    startActivity(chooser); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is the solution. Use the below code, works perfectly...Got the
> solution after research.... :)

```
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "blah blah subject" + "&body=" + 
"blah blah body" + "&to=" + "sendme@me.com");  
testIntent.setData(data);  
startActivity(testIntent);
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution for my problem!
Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Modified from dreamdevelope & Syed Rafaqat Hussain. Better do Uri.encode for the subject and body. Tested on Samsung S20 Android 13 and Huawei Mate 20 Android 10.

```
fun sendEmail(activity: AppCompatActivity,subject:String,body:String,email:String){
    val testIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    val encodeSubject = Uri.encode(subject)
    val encodeBody = Uri.encode(body)

    val uriContent =buildString {
        append("mailto:?subject=")
        append(encodeSubject)
        append("&body=")
        append(encodeBody)
        append("&to=")
        append(email)
    }
    val data = Uri.parse(uriContent)
    testIntent.data = data
    activity.startActivity(testIntent)
}
```