# Android - Crashes when trying to send email

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a little app just for test. I have a button that triggers a 'send email' intent.
When I test this on my mobile phone, it crashes when i hit the send email button.

here's my curent code:

Listener for the send button:

```
    btn_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            sendMail( prefs.getString(TEXT_VALUE_KEY, "") );

        }

    });
```

Send email function:

```
            private void sendMail(String message) {
            //Método de chamada a aplicação android para envio de mail
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));

        }
```

Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: Where's the stacktrace?

Comment: At this moment, I can only test it on the phone, which makes it all much more difficult.

Comment: The phone records the same information to LogCat as does the emulator.

Comment: could be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280166/intent-with-settypemessage-rfc822-for-android-api-level-before-2-3-3